# move constructor for std::runtime_error

Tags: string, exception, c++11, move, c++14

Why does `std::runtime_error` not provide a constructor accepting an `std::string&&`? Looking at [the constructors for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), it has a move constructor, but the `noexcept` specification is only there for C++14, not C++11. Was this a mistake, a deadline that was missed or am I missing something?

Comment: If `std::runtime_error` had a constructor taking `std::string&&`, it certainly would not be a move constructor. A move constructor would take `std::runtime_error&&`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: judging from the beginning it seems your question is about `runtime_error`, but then you switch to `std::string`. What point are you trying to make?

Comment: @AndyProwl: `std::runtime_error` may presently be constructed from a `const std::string&` or from a `const char* what_arg`. He's asking why it cannot be constructed from a `std::string&&`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, but he seems to be making a point about exception-safety by mentioning the `noexcept` qualification of `string`'s move constructor, which I'm not entirely following.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if the question caused confusion. The question is why `std::runtime_error(std::string&&)` is not present.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`explicit runtime_error(string&&);`

does not exist simply because it would not provide any optimization.

As it turns out, a C++11-conforming `runtime_error` does not internally store a `std::string`.  The reason is that the copy members of `runtime_error` must not throw exceptions.  Otherwise the wrong exception could get thrown when the compiler copies the exception object in the process of throwing it.

This implies that `runtime_error` needs to store a non-mutable reference counted string.  However C++11 outlaws the COW-implementation for `std::string`.  Implementations of `std::string` have moved to a "short-string-optimization" which must allocate on copy construction if the length of the string is beyond the "short limit".  And there is no limit on the length of strings used to construct a `runtime_error`.

So effectively C++11 (and forward) contains two implementations of strings:

1. `std::string` : This is typically a short-string-optimized type with a copy constructor and copy assignment that is capable of throwing exceptions.
2. `std::runtime_error` :  This is (or holds) an immutable reference-counted string.  This will never throw on copy construction or copy assignment.

And

`explicit runtime_error(string&&);`

can never (efficiently) transfer resources from the "type 1" string to the "type 2" string.

Comment: What would the type 2 string look like, out of interest? (If it's a black-boxed, hidden, implementation-defined internal type then that's a sufficient answer.)

Comment: It could look like the non-mutating parts of a C++03 COW-based `std::string`.  Indeed, that is exactly what libc++ did.  Its type 2 string has an ABI identical to the gcc-4.2 `std::string` so that `runtime_error` can be thrown from libc++ and caught using libstdc++ (and vice-versa), *within the same application*.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: When libc++ and libstdc++ are dylibs, and when an app is composed of many dylibs, it becomes quite likely that during a transition period on a platform such as OS X, an app will unwittingly, indirectly, link to both libc++ and libstdc++, unless said app can directly control the building of all of the dylibs it uses.

Comment: Similarly, libstdc++ in GCC5 still uses the old COW `std::string` in its exception types (via an opaque type and some hideous hackery), even when the new SSO `std::string` is the one visible to users. This should support throwing `std::runtime_error` in code using any `std::string` from GCC4, GCC5 or libc++, and catching it in code using a different `std::string`.